# i schedule a Timer to read RSSI using readRSSI function ,but the timer stops when my app go into background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, rssi

I schedule a Timer to read RSSI using readRSSI function
,but the timer stops when my app go into background. Maybe there is a good method to get RSSI value from peripheral's notification when app comes into background
. But I don't know how to do.
Could anybody help me?
Anyone has a better method?

Comment: iOS apps don't run in the background unless you specifically specify that they need to, and then only for a short period of time, so all your timers will be paused until the app returns to the foreground unless you implement background execution (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the same problem, and I have two idea.

1.

First, you should have some service that got corebluetooth delegate periodly.
F
or my example, I have a battery service that I can got delegate with `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` periodly.

Second, set readRSSI function in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`. And don't forget to set background mode with Corebluetooth.So now you can got the RSSI updating when update battery value.

This works fine for me, but I got another idea from some sample code.

2.

Use the code below whenever you want to start the RSSI reader:

```
NSTimer *rssiTimer; 
[rssiTimer invalidate];    
rssiTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:peripheral selector:@selector(readRSSI) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:rssiTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

It works fine for me too.

Comment: i have got this idea yesterday,and i try to solve it by modify device.but the question is , i see some apps that they can achieve distance alert without modifying my device.

Comment: I don't exactly know what "modify your device" means.Can you detailed describe what your question is?

Comment: Is this is the case for iOS7?

Comment: The second solution is not going to work as the timer is suspended in background after a while and it will not be resumed automatically. The first solution, however, is a possible way to go.