# Reading RSSI of Bluetooth peripheral in background using Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

An iPhone app that I'm currently developing needs to read the RSSI of a peripheral every second as soon as it has established a local connection using `CBCentralManager`, both in foreground and background. This means that setting `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` to `true` when calling `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)` is out of the question since it is both ignored when an app is running in the background and it only enables RSSI updates via `CBCentralManagerDelegate`'s `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)` method, at this point the peripheral is not connected yet.

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674038/405603) I implemented a characteristic in the peripheral that has a `notify` property and updates itself every second. Within my app I use `CBPeripheral`'s `setNotifyValue(_:for:)` method to get notified of the characteristic updates via `peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)`. Within this method I call `peripheral.readRSSI()` and get an RSSI update roughly every second via `peripheral(_:didReadRSSI:error:)`.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
...
peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristicUpdatingEverySecond)
...

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    peripheral.readRSSI()
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {

    print("Peripheral \(peripheral) read RSSI: \(RSSI)")
}
```

Combined with a proper implementation of Core Bluetooth state preservation and restoration this seems to work quite well. Even though this seems to be an acceptable solution I am still wondering if there are other solutions that do not rely on a self-updating characteristic in the peripheral.

I have contemplated using an iBeacon (parallel to the Bluetooth peripheral) but this is not a good solution for us since it can be easily spoofed, we rely on certain verification methods when setting up the connection to ensure that the peripheral is genuine.

Does anyone have experience with polling the RSSI of a Bluetooth peripheral in both foreground and background app states using Core Bluetooth? Have you found an alternative/different/better solution?

Comment: Is your peripheral a hardware device (whose firmware you control) or another iOS device running a `CBPeripheralManager` in the background? Because if the latter, you're back to the same problem, how do you update the value of the peripheral's "heartbeat" characteristic in the background?